# count the number of upper case and lower case characters in word

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
def Charater(): 
    UpperCount = 0 
    LowerCount = 0
    word = input('Enter a word: ')
    for letter in word:
        if letter == letter.upper 
            UpperCount = UpperCount + 1
            return UpperCount
        else:
            LowerCount = LowerCount + 1
            return LowerCount

print(Charater())
```

Please don't judge me if this looks bad. But am a beginner I am trying to make the code count how many upper and lower case characters in a word which is inputted by the user. Each time I do this it returns 1. (Its probably my if statement). can someone please point out the problem and tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: You are `return`ing inside your loop, and in both of your conditional branches inside your loop, so you will at most only ever have a single iteration. You probably want to `return` outside your loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) and [`str.islower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) to find the count of uppercased and lowercased characters respectively as:

```
>>> my_word = "HelLo WorLd"
>>> lower_count = sum(map(str.islower, my_word))
>>> lower_count
6

>>> upper_count = sum(map(str.isupper, my_word))
>>> upper_count
4
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use `sum` if I just want to count when sum boolean condition is `True`, so `sum(map(str.islower, word))` for example. It also has the advantage of being python 2-3 compatible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga makes sense. Also as I see that OP is looking for Python3 solution, updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Count in one line using `collections.Counter`, generator comprehension and a nested ternary:

```
import collections

my_word = "HelLo WorLd"
c = collections.Counter("upper" if x.isupper() else "lower" if x.islower() else "" for x in my_word)
print(c)
```

result:

```
Counter({'lower': 6, 'upper': 4, '': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```py
 def count_by_case(string):
     upper = sum(letter.isupper() for letter in string)
     lower = sum(letter.islower() for letter in string)
     return lower, upper

 string = "MyString"
 lower, upper = count_by_case(string)
 print("{!r} contains {} upper and {} lower case letters".format(string, upper, lower))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a short function

```
def count_up_and_low(word):
    u = [x for x in word if x.isupper()]
    l = [x for x in word if x.islower()]

    return len(u), len(v)
```

Comment: you should just use `'some_string'.isupper()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
def up_low(str):
    upper_count=0
    lower_count=0
    for x in str:
        if x.isupper():
            upper_count+=1
        else:
            lower_count+=1
    print(f'number of upper case letter {upper_count}')
    print(f'number of lower case letter {lower_count}')
```